# Updating List of Objects Saving to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list which takes in two objects, I want to update the same column in each object and save it to the database. I have tried this but it doesn't work. The correct objects are in the list as I set a dropdownbox to check if they were.

```
List<Fighter> item = fight.Fighters.ToList<Fighter>();
item.ToList().ForEach(c => c.Draw++);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Any ideas?

---

I have a many to many relationship between fight and fighter, two fighters belong to a fight.

Edit:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HandleResult(Fight fight)
    {

        List<Fighter> item = fight.Fighters.ToList<Fighter>();

        ... //Code here that isnt related

        foreach (var i in item)
                {
                    item.ToList().ForEach(c => c.Draw++);
                    db.Fighters.Add(i);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
     }
```

So as you can see in the httpPost, I want to get the fighters that are involved in the fight and add 1 to the attribute Draw that is in the fighter entity.

Comment: what is `fight.Fighters`? Does it have anything to do with `db` (which I assume is the db context)?

Comment: Fight is another entity which has a many to many relationship with fighters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to save it without actually adding it to the database tables.  It looks like you are using Entity Framework.  Assuming so, you'd do something like the following.

```
List<Fighter> item = db.fight.Fighters.ToList<Fighter>();
item.ToList().ForEach(c => c.Draw++);
foreach (var i in item)
{
    db.fight.Fighters.AddObject(i);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

EDIT: Updated syntax.  It wasn't correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I knew I wasn't saving it correctly, doing this I get the following error Error 1 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MMAScreenProject.Models.Fighter>' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MMAScreenProject.Models.Fighter>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @RobertPallin Sorry, syntax wasn't correct.  You should be able to iterate through the loop, then call AddObject for each item in the loop, adding it to your db context;

Comment: Still nothing on that. Thanks for the help again. AddObject can't be found, I tried a simple Add but that doesn't do the job either. Also, the "fight" is an instance of another entity that has a many to many relationship with Fighters if that makes a difference.

Comment: @RobertPallin Could you post more code surrounding this?  I'm thinking that while my answer is the correct way to do this, there may be more surrounding it than was originally deduced.

Comment: Edited the question, if youre still having trouble understanding what I'm trying to do I will explain it in more detail, thanks very much for the help.

Comment: @RobertPallin are you sure that item isn't an empty list?  Also is fight.Fighter the same type as db.Fighter?  And it looks like your edit isn't right. You should modify item before the foreach loop that adds them to the db

Comment: No fight.Fighters is accessing the Fighters that have a relationship with the Fight entity. The list is filled maybe my syntax or logic is wrong somewhere. The list is not definitely not empty.

Comment: What type is db and how is it instantiated?  In addition can you post the full namespacing of fight.Fighter and db.Fighter please?

Comment: The database using a context that sets the tables with dbset. 
System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Fighter> MMAScreenContext.Fighters

Comment: It's just too difficult to tell what's going on.  That said, i'm still more than happy to help.  If you'd like, feel free to zip up your solution and email it to the address listed on my profile.

Comment: I'll have a look at it later and if I cant figure it out ill email you thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like db.Add(object), before doing db.SaveChanges();